# can I use JNI/JNA to work with libcrypto-3-x64.dll?

Tags: java, openssl, jna

I have install OPENSSL in my computer, and there is a file named "libcrypto-3-x64.dll" in my "system32" folder.

Can I use JNI or JNA to work with libcrypto-3-x64.dll ?

I can use JNI to work with a dll which maked by myself (just hello world).

I can use JNA to work with win32 API, but how can I work with libcrypto-3-x64.dll ?

I dumped the method names of libcrypto-3-x64.dll like below:

```
Dump of file libcrypto-3-x64.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for libcrypto-3-x64.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
        5382 number of functions
        5382 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 000079FF ACCESS_DESCRIPTION_free
          2    1 000056C3 ACCESS_DESCRIPTION_it
          3    2 000049AD ACCESS_DESCRIPTION_new
          4    3 0000370B ADMISSIONS_free
          5    4 00001CCB ADMISSIONS_get0_admissionAuthority
          6    5 00005272 ADMISSIONS_get0_namingAuthority
          7    6 000072D9 ADMISSIONS_get0_professionInfos
          8    7 00007B5D ADMISSIONS_it
          9    8 00002176 ADMISSIONS_new
...
```

but don't know how to use it, maybe I can't use it ?

Comment: This sounds like a giant [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What are you actually hoping to implement and why do you think you need JNI+OpenSSL for it? You could just use Java's BouncyCastle library or some of its libsodium wrappers or ...

Comment: @Botje just for learning programming. I think if it can use just a dll file for encryption, it will be very usefull

Comment: For JNI you will need to write or generate (eg SWIG) wrapper code that converts from Java types to the structures that OpenSSL expects. JNA will require much the same.

Comment: @Botje I searched google, and openssl website, just can't find the structures that OpenSSL expects, maybe Openssl don't want other use their dll to programming?~

Comment: Random [first search hit](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_params.html) talks about a `EVP_PKEY_CTX` and `OSSL_PARAM` struct. I suggest you try writing OpenSSL-using code in plain C or C++ before you add JNA to your list of headaches.

Comment: @Botje oh , thank you very much ,this link is very useful, thanks.  it seems I can use it , but I need to study it first, I am not familiar with c/c++, all I need is study all.

Comment: If you’re doing this for learning purposes, JNI is eventually going to be replaced by the [java.lang.foreign](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/package-summary.html) package.  It’s well documented, it works well, and it allows for safe memory access even with native functions in most circumstances.